# Python Multiprocessing: different results with different number of processes

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am working on some Python code, and need to have it run over large amounts of data, therefore I've decided to use the multiprocessing module.  I find though, that as I vary the number of processes, I get different results which is obviously undesirable.

I have some randomness in my code, but I fix the random seed as soon as the program executes (the random seed is simply used to select labeled and unlabeled datapoints) in the central process.  Sub-processes have no randomness, and simply compute matrix or vector operations.

Here is the relevant code.  I use the relevant numpy and scipy modules.  The remaining code just does setup, and is not relevant to the problem at hand.

The function `update_pq_wrapper` spawns the sub-processes.  The functions `update_p` and `update_q` are the functions that are called on sub-sets of the data.  `update_pq_wrapper` gathers results from the sub-processes and puts them together. `W` is a global variable that represents an affinity matrix.

```
def update_p(startIdx, endIdx, betaMatrix, out_q):
  p = np.zeros((endIdx-startIdx, max(LABELS)+1))
  W_colsum = W.sum(1)
  for i in xrange(startIdx, endIdx): #for i 0 to numExamples - 1                                                                                                                                                                            
    dist = np.zeros(max(LABELS)+1, dtype=np.float64)                                                                                                                                                           
    g = gamma(W_colsum, i)
    dist = np.exp(betaMatrix[i,:] / g)
    dist /= np.sum(dist)
    p[i-startIdx,:] = dist
  out_q.put(p)

def update_q(startIdx, endIdx, sumMatrix, out_q):
  q = np.zeros((endIdx-startIdx, max(LABELS)+1))
  W_rowsum = W.sum(0)
  for i in xrange(startIdx, endIdx):
    dist = np.zeros(max(LABELS)+1, dtype=np.float64)
    labeled = 1 if L[i] else 0
    dist = (R[i,:]*labeled + mu*sumMatrix[i,:]) / (labeled + mu*W_rowsum[0,i])
    dist /= np.sum(dist)
    q[i-startIdx,:] = dist
  out_q.put(q)

def update_pq_wrapper(curIter, chunksize, mat, update_step='p'):
  startIdx = xrange(0, dataset_size, chunksize)
  prevIter = 1 - curIter
  procs = []
  out_q = Queue()
  for i in range(ncores):    #now, start each of the child processes that assembles the matrices individually                                                                                                                               
    start = startIdx[i]
    end = dataset_size if i == ncores-1 else startIdx[i+1]
    if update_step == 'p':
        proc = Process(target=update_p, args=(start, end, mat, out_q))
    else:
        proc = Process(target=update_q, args=(start, end, mat, out_q))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
  if update_step == 'p':    #once completed, collect results                                                                                                                                                                                
    distMat = P1 if curIter else P0
  else:
    distMat = Q1 if curIter else Q0
  for i in range(ncores):
    p_chunk = out_q.get()
    start = startIdx[i]
    end = dataset_size if i == ncores-1 else startIdx[i+1]
    distMat[start:end,:] = p_chunk
  for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

Now, if I run this with just 1 process, I get the following results (accuracy for 5 iterations):
2.16 --> 26.56 --> 27.37 --> 27.63 --> 27.83

However, if I run this with 2 processes, I get the following:
2.16 --> 3.72 --> 18.74 --> 14.81 --> 16.51

And with 4 processes:
2.16 --> 13.78 --> 13.85 --> 15.67 --> 13.12

I'm not sure what the reason for this behavior is, especially considering the code pasted above.

Avneesh

**EDIT (January 15, 2013, 3:34 PM Pacific Time**

As requested by some people, I'm copy-pasting the whole code below, and also a brief explanation of what exactly the code is meant to do.

The basic idea is that I have a graph, represented by an affinity matrix `W`.  Each node represents a probability distribution over the set of possible labels for each node.  So for labeled examples, the nodes have a degenerate probability distribution, with a value of 1 at the row corresponding to a label, and 0 everywhere else.  For unlabeled nodes, the resulting label for each node is a distribution, and one can take the MAP point estimate of this distribution to get the label for that point.  For more details on the approach, please see [here](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/subramanya11a.html).  The objective function is solved using a technique known as alternating minimization, wherein 2 probability distributions are proposed (`p` and `q` in the code) and we iterate until the distributions converge to the same values.

As suggested by one of the commenters, I shifted the `proc.join()` part so that it is above the operations that occur post joining.  This seems to cause the code to not progress beyond the stage where the sub-processes are spawned, forcing me to interrupt execution from the keyboard. Perhaps I'm just doing something wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, commands, string, cPickle
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.linalg as la
from math import ceil
from time import clock
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty

np.random.seed(42)
if not len(sys.argv) == 9:
  print 'ERROR: Usage: python alternating_minimization.py <binary data or sim matrix> <labels_file> <iterations> <num cores> <label percent> <v> <mu> <alpha>'
  sys.exit()

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# Main Parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
similarity_file = sys.argv[1] #output of simgraph_construction.py                                                                                                                                                                             
labels_file = sys.argv[2]
niterations = int(sys.argv[3])
ncores = int(sys.argv[4])

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# meta parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
label_percent = float(sys.argv[5])
v = float(sys.argv[6])
mu = float(sys.argv[7])
alpha = float(sys.argv[8])

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# load the data file (output of simgraph_construction.py) which is already in numpy format                                                                                                                                                    
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
W = cPickle.load(open(similarity_file, 'r'))
#print some summary statistics about the similarity matrix file                                                                                                                                                                               
print "Number of examples: %d"%(W.shape[0])
print "Sim Matrix: nnz = %d, density = %.2f percent, average # of neighbors per example: %.2f"%(W.nnz, 100*(float(W.nnz)/(W.shape[0]**2)), float(W.nnz)/W.shape[0])

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# load the labels                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
def convertLabels(labels):
  unique_labels = np.unique(labels)
  label_dict = {}
  idx = 0
  for label in unique_labels:
    label_dict[label] = idx
    idx += 1
  return label_dict

LABELS = np.load(labels_file)
print "Number of unique labels: %d"%(np.unique(LABELS).shape)
label_dict = convertLabels(LABELS)
NEW_LABELS = np.array([label_dict[label] for label in LABELS])
dataset_size = LABELS.shape[0]
LABELS = NEW_LABELS
W = W + alpha*sp.identity(dataset_size)

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# define the labeled and unlabeled idxs                                                                                                                                                                                                       
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
def make_test_set():
  idx = np.random.rand(dataset_size)
  l = (idx < label_percent)
  u = (idx >= label_percent)
  return l,u

L,U = make_test_set()
def createRDistribution(label_bool, labels):
  rows = np.array(range(0, dataset_size), dtype=int)
  label_idx = np.where(~label_bool)
  rows = np.delete(rows, label_idx)
  cols = np.delete(labels, label_idx)
  vals = np.ones((rows.shape[0],1)).ravel()
  sparseR = sp.csc_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)), shape=(dataset_size, max(labels)+1))
  return sparseR

########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# make the distributions for the data                                                                                                                                                                                                         
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                      
R = createRDistribution(L, LABELS) #labeled distribution is sparse                                                                                                                                                                            
classNoLabel = np.where(R.sum(0) == 0)
#print classNoLabel #need to figure out how many classes are unrepresented in the labeld set                                                                                                                                                  
Q0 = np.zeros((dataset_size, max(LABELS)+1), dtype=np.double)
Q0 += 1.0 / Q0.shape[1]
Q1 = np.zeros((dataset_size, max(LABELS)+1), dtype=np.double)
P0 = np.zeros((dataset_size, max(LABELS)+1), dtype=np.double)
P1 = np.zeros((dataset_size, max(LABELS)+1), dtype=np.double)

def gamma(W_sum,i): #W_sum is sum across all columns of sim matrix W                                                                                                                                                                          
  return v + mu * W_sum[i]

def update_p(startIdx, endIdx, betaMatrix, out_q):
  p = np.zeros((endIdx-startIdx, max(LABELS)+1))
  W_colsum = W.sum(1)
  for i in xrange(startIdx, endIdx): #for i 0 to numExamples - 1                                                                                                                                                                            
    dist = np.zeros(max(LABELS)+1, dtype=np.float64)                                                                                                                                                           
    g = gamma(W_colsum, i)
    dist = np.exp(betaMatrix[i,:] / g)
    dist /= np.sum(dist)
    p[i-startIdx,:] = dist
  out_q.put(p)

def update_q(startIdx, endIdx, sumMatrix, out_q):
  q = np.zeros((endIdx-startIdx, max(LABELS)+1))
  W_rowsum = W.sum(0)
  for i in xrange(startIdx, endIdx):
    dist = np.zeros(max(LABELS)+1, dtype=np.float64)
    labeled = 1 if L[i] else 0
    dist = (R[i,:]*labeled + mu*sumMatrix[i,:]) / (labeled + mu*W_rowsum[0,i])
    dist /= np.sum(dist)
    q[i-startIdx,:] = dist
  out_q.put(q)

def update_pq_wrapper(curIter, chunksize, mat, update_step='p'):
  startIdx = xrange(0, dataset_size, chunksize)
  prevIter = 1 - curIter
  procs = []
  out_q = Queue()
  for i in range(ncores):    #now, start each of the child processes that assembles the matrices individually                                                                                                                               
    start = startIdx[i]
    end = dataset_size if i == ncores-1 else startIdx[i+1]
    if update_step == 'p':
        proc = Process(target=update_p, args=(start, end, mat, out_q))
    else:
        proc = Process(target=update_q, args=(start, end, mat, out_q))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
  if update_step == 'p':    #once completed, collect results                                                                                                                                                                                
    distMat = P1 if curIter else P0
  else:
    distMat = Q1 if curIter else Q0
  for i in range(ncores):
    p_chunk = out_q.get()
    start = startIdx[i]
    end = dataset_size if i == ncores-1 else startIdx[i+1]
    distMat[start:end,:] = p_chunk
  for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

def compute_tvdist(P,Q):
  tv_dist = 0
  for i in range(0, dataset_size):
    tv_dist += max(np.absolute(P[i,:] - Q[i,:]))
  return tv_dist/dataset_size

def main(argv):
  accuracyArr = []
  tvdistArr = []
  print >> sys.stderr, 'Starting %d iterations...' % niterations
  chunksize = int(ceil(dataset_size/float(ncores)))
  for n in xrange(1,niterations+1):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Iteration %d' % n
    idx = n % 2
    q_prev = Q1 if not idx else Q0
    p_cur = P1 if idx else P0
    #print q_prev                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    start_time = clock()
    mat = -v + mu*(W*(np.log(q_prev)-1))
    end_time = clock()
    #print mat                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    print "Time taken to compute Beta Matrix: %.2f seconds"%(end_time-start_time)
    start_time=clock()
    update_pq_wrapper(idx, chunksize, mat, 'p')
    end_time=clock()
    print "Time taken to update P matrix: %.2f seconds"%(end_time-start_time)
    if not n == niterations:
      start_time = clock()
      mat = W.T*p_cur
      end_time = clock()
      print "Time taken to compute Sum Matrix: %.2f seconds"%(end_time-start_time)
      start_time = clock()
      update_pq_wrapper(idx, chunksize, mat, 'q')
      end_time = clock()
      print "Time taken to update Q matrix: %.2f seconds"%(end_time-start_time)
    ## Evaluation ##                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    evalMat = P1 if idx else P0                                                                                                                                                   
    predLabel = np.argmax(evalMat, axis=1) #gives the index (column)                                                                                                                                                                      
    accuracy = float(np.sum(predLabel[np.where(U)] == LABELS[np.where(U)]) )/ LABELS[np.where(U)].shape[0]
    print "Accuracy: %.2f"%(accuracy*100)
    accuracyArr.append(accuracy)
    totalVar = []
    if n != niterations:
        tv_dist = compute_tvdist(P1, Q1) if idx else compute_tvdist(P0, Q0)
    else:
        tv_dist = compute_tvdist(P1, Q0) if idx else compute_tvdist(P0, Q1)
    print "Average Total Variation Distance is %.3f"%(tv_dist)
    tvdistArr.append(tv_dist)
  print "Summary of final probability density matrix: "
  print evalMat
  print '\t'.join([str(round(acc,4)) for acc in accuracyArr])
```

Comment: Should you process the queue after joining the procs? Or try out_q.get(block=True)?

Comment: Avneesh, I don't understand what you're trying to do. What does p and q refer to? Also, this would be easier if you gave us a runnable example.

Comment: DrSkippy and Nick ODell - please see my edits above.

Comment: Also if you would like for me to upload some data (that's an input to the code above), please let me know. I'm not too familiar with the standards and expectations on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This has been solved.  I don't know what I was thinking, but clearly when returning from sub-processes the data will be written asynchronously and not in the order I was expecting (order of the rows).  An easy fix is to have sub-processes return a tuple of the data as well as an indicator of which part of the data it was working on, and then using this information to piece the resulting matrix back together.